# How to use output of 1st query as input for 2nd one?

Tags: sql, oracle

I was trying to do this to avoid manual work. not sure if it is possible or not.

First query:

```
SELECT Max(version), Project 
FROM Table_1 
GROUP_BY project
```

Second query:

```
SELECT B.project, B.version, B.defect, B.Assign, C.staus 
FROM Table_2 B 
JOIN Table_3 C ON B.project = C.project AND B.version = C.version
WHERE (B.project = 1 AND B.version = 2)
```

I want all the latest projects version in that database automatically picked up from the first query and entered in 2nd query.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It's a **query** - not a "quarry" ....

Comment: @marc_s I thought it was quite apt, in a data mining sense - this isn't very deep ;)

Comment: @CaiusJard: the **queries** look too simple and too straightforward for a data **mining** project that would justify using the term "quarry", IMHO :-)

Answer (score 0):

Join them:

```
SELECT B.project, B.version, B.defect, B.Assign, C.staus 
FROM Table_2 B JOIN Table_3 C ON B.project = C.project 
                             AND B.version = C.version
join (select max(version) max_version,
             project
      from table_1
      group by project
     ) x on x.project = b.project 
        and x.max_version = b.version;
```

Comment: Thank you for help it worked. I removed the last line (and x.max_version = b.version) because the oracle was throwing error(Unknown identifier) for that.

Comment: You can't remove the last line; there's no point in running the subquery to find the max in order to restrict the other rows to the most recent version if you go and then throw away the "most recent verson" info you wanted! If it says `invalid identifier` it's either because the max_version alias is unknown because you didn't put *join (select max(version) **max_version***, `<-- LOOK, IT'S ALIASED AS max_version` like Littlefoot did, or because there is no `b.version` column - which is your mistake for including it on your original query

Comment: @AKA_Luffy Also maybe worth pointing out you might have a typo in `c.staus` - status?

Comment: @CaiusJard Thanks it is working now. There was a mistake at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Using a cte can make things easy to read:

```
WITH quarry1 AS
(
  SELECT Max(version) as version, Project FROM Table_1 
  GROUP_BY project
)
SELECT B.project, B.version, B.defect, B.Assign, C.staus 
FROM 
    Table_2 B 
    INNER JOIN Table_3 C ON B.project = C.project AND B.version = C.version
    INNER JOIN quarry1 D ON B.project = D.project AND B.version = D.version
WHERE 
    (B.project = 1 and B.version = 2) -- you should probably remove this

  --if you leave the WHERE clause in there is probably no point running the 
  --query that calculates the MAX. I left it in to demo how to put two
  --queries together - i.e. I answered literally the question you asked
  --rather than guessing at what you meant to ask. Think on and fix this
```

You need to give the MAX an alias - I just used `version` again. You should endeavour to give tables and aliases good meaningful names though; table1/2/3 a/b/c/d isn't very descriptive and will make the query harder to read, write and debug

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can use `in`:

```
SELECT B.project, B.version, B.defect, B.Assign, C.staus 
FROM Table_2 B JOIN
     Table_3 C
     ON B.project = C.project AND B.version = C.version
WHERE (B.project, B.version) IN (SELECT Max(version), Project 
                                 FROM Table_1 
                                 GROUP BY project
                                );
```

Or a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT B.project, B.version, B.defect, B.Assign, C.staus 
FROM Table_2 B JOIN
     Table_3 C
     ON B.project = C.project AND B.version = C.version
WHERE B.version = (SELECT MAX(t1.version) 
                   FROM Table_1 t1
                   WHERE t1.project = B.project
                  );
```